# метод eqals проверка нескольких данных одновременно

Tags: java, методы

Подскажите написал вот такой код,хочу понять как я могу сразу проверить и name и id

```
public class Eql {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat("Gorg",12);
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("Gorg",12);

        //String cat3 = name2; //"Gorg123".substring(0,4);
        //System.out.println(cat3);
        System.out.println(cat1.eqals(cat2));
        System.out.println(cat1.eqals(cat2));


    }
}
class Cat{
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Cat(String name,int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean eqals(Object obj) {
        Cat neweqals = (Cat)obj;
        return this.id ==neweqals.id;

    }
}
```

Comment: this.id == neweqals.id && this.name.equals(neweqals.name)

Comment: Вообще же любой класс наследует класс Object, а него есть реализация метода equals по умолчанию. Почитайте про это - вы создали новый метод, а не переписали старый, что нужно было бы сделать

Comment: То есть получается нужно написать 2 метода которые  возвращают bolean?я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Прочитайте сперва: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1340-peregruzka-metodov-equals-i-hashcode-v-java

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean eqals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Cat) && (id == ((Cat) obj).id) && name.equals(((Cat)obj).name);
}
```

P.S. Было бы неплохо переопределить метод equals, для этого нужно поправить название метода.